# SharedPreferences not saving boolean attribute

Tags: android, json, arraylist, boolean, sharedpreferences

I am facing an issue with saving an object boolean in SharedPreferences. The object (part of ArrayList "questions") contains a boolean "**recentAnswer**".
If I change the boolean value and want to use it in another activity, the value is **still the old one**.

Here is my saveData-method from Activity 1:

```
private void saveData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(questions);
        editor.putString("task list", json);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

and here's where I use it in order to save the changed boolean value (Activity 1):

```
private void checkAnswer(Button answerButton){
        if (answerButton.getText().equals(questions.get(currentQuestion).getAnswer1())){
            questions.get(currentQuestion).recentAnswer = true;
        }
        else{
            questions.get(currentQuestion).recentAnswer = false;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, Boolean.toString(questions.get(currentQuestion).recentAnswer), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        saveData();
    }
```

Firstly, I load the ArrayList in Activity 2:

```
private void loadData(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Question>>(){}.getType();
        questions = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        if(questions == null){
            questions = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

And then I want to get the "recentAnswer" values (Activity 2):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistics);

        loadData();
        for (Question element : questions){
            int recentWrong;
            if (!element.recentAnswer){
                recentWrong++;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(recentWrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

No matter, how I change the values in Activity 1, in Activity 2 "recentWrong" is always = 0, even though I am accessing the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(questions);
        editor.putString("task list", json);
```

Do not do this ever. First off is you are not checking and do not know what the value questions may hold and you also should not save something like that in SharedPrefs.

If you have several questions, then save each question together with its response in SharedPrefs and if you need to save an answer that you want to check against later in code, use string values stored in the res->strings.xml.
If the question is too long, find a way to concat it or use the res->string-arrays.xml and keep the questions there, then reference them from there.

You need to go back a bit and take a look at how to design programs in Java, Kotlin or any language for that matter. This is what comes after you learn programming basics.